# Format routerLink param url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, routerlink

In my angular 2 app I have defined a router link like :

```
<a *ngFor="let demo of demos" [routerLink]="['demo', demo.name]">example</a>
```

Currently I am getting demo.name as "example.net/demo/A%20%demo%20%test". I want to format this as "example.net/demo/a-demo-test" to show in the browser address bar.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to replace spaces with dashes. Eg: `[routerLink]="['demo', demo.name.replace(/\s+/g, '-')]"`

Comment: @JaroslawK. I have routing defined separately in each module.

Comment: @Titus I tried your solution this gives me error "Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token / at column 35 in".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use functions inside `routerLink`.  So you can use a function in your component:

```
  hyphenateUrlParams(str:string){
    return str.replace(' ', '-');
  }
```

And use it in your `routerLink`:

```
[routerLink]="['/demo', hyphenateUrlParams(demo.name)]"
```

This provides much more re-usability than mutating variables directly inside the `routerLink`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a pipe that converts spaces to hyphens.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'kebabCase'
})
export class KebabCasePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
      return value.replace(' ', '-');
  }

}
```

Use the pipe in your links:

```
<a *ngFor="let demo of demos" [routerLink]="['demo', demo.name | kebabCase]">example</a>
```